# Mac OS X Lion Terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

I have a question about my terminal. When I started out working with Rails on my Mac terminal, I would have lines that looked like this as the route for my $:

```
Nicholass-MacBook-Pro:sample_app nbkincaid$ rails console
```

But now, I get lines that look like this:

```
pal-nat184-103-166:desktop nbkincaid$
```

I'm pretty sure that I didn't change anything, so why does it give me the `pal-nat....$` instead of the `Nicholas...$`?

Comment: I'd say you've changed something or that your bash shell is set up to display the host name of your computer and you're on a network assigning you a name.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg Instead of saying that in a comment, you should say that in an answer.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. It looks like when I log on to my school's wireless network, thats when I notice it, but when I'm on my wireless network at home, it reverts to my name.

Comment: @jason well I guess :).  glad to help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string "pal-nat184-103-166" is your computer's hostname, which can be changed dynamically by routers or other network devices through DHCP.

If you want to set it to a static string, you can do so by adding the following line to /etc/hostconfig

```
HOSTNAME=Nicholass-MacBook-Pro
```

Comment: You should also check the Sharing preference pane to make sure you have your computer name set to what you want your machine to show up as on the network.

Comment: Add this to "questions I've always wondered about but never sought through to investigate why"

Comment: Also, confirmed that you can just change the setting in Sharing pref pane.

Comment: Tim, what do you mean by this?

Comment: @nbkincaid Tim meant he's seen this problem and always wondered about it, but just fixed it and otherwise never cared to ask anyone about it.

Answer (score -1):

You probably messed up your `~/.bash_profile` file.

Export the S1 shell variable.

For example, I have this one:

```
export PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

Remember to re-open the console after changing `bash_profile` file.

https://makandracards.com/makandra/1090-customize-your-bash-prompt